# Model summary is empty

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, keras-tuner

I am trying to build a neural network using keras functional API and to train the network I am using keras tuner. The model consists of some embedding layers and then some dense layers:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kerastuner.tuners import RandomSearch, BayesianOptimization

def build_model(hp):
  model = keras.Sequential()
  activation = hp.Choice('activation',['relu','tanh','linear'])

  optimizer = hp.Choice('optimizer', ['adam', 'sgd', 'rmsprop'])
  in_layers = list()
  em_layers = list()
  for i in range(len(X_train_enc)):
    # calculate the number of unique inputs
    n_labels = len(np.unique(X_train_enc[i]))
    # define input layer
    in_layer = Input(shape=(1,))
    # define embedding layer
    em_layer = Embedding(n_labels, round(n_labels/2))(in_layer)
    # store layers
    in_layers.append(in_layer)
    em_layers.append(em_layer)

  merge = keras.layers.concatenate(em_layers)
  x = Flatten()(merge)
  
  for i in range(hp.Int('num_layers', 1, 6)):
    units = hp.Int(
          'units_' + str(i),
          min_value=8,
          max_value=128,
          step=16
    )
    x = Dense(units, activation=activation)(x)
    drop_rate = hp.Choice('drop_rate_' + str(i),
                            [
                              0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4,
                              0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9
                            ])
    x = keras.layers.Dropout(rate=drop_rate)(x)


  output = Dense(1, activation='linear')(x)
  model = keras.models.Model(inputs=in_layers, outputs=output)

  model.compile(
      optimizer=optimizer,
      loss=keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(reduction="auto", name="mean_squared_error"), 
      metrics=['accuracy']
  )
  return model
```

To use the tuner following code is executed:

```
tuner = BayesianOptimization(
    build_model,
    objective='accuracy',
    max_trials=25,
    executions_per_trial=5,
    directory='drive/MyDrive/Master/train_model/nn_first_reg',
    project_name='nn_bayes_first_reg',
    seed=10)


tuner.search(X_train_enc,y_train)
tuner.results_summary()
best_hyperparameters = tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(1)[0]
model = tuner.hypermodel.build(best_hyperparameters)
history = model.fit(X_train_enc, y_train, epochs=50, validation_split=0.2)
val_acc_per_epoch = history.history['val_accuracy']
best_epoch = val_acc_per_epoch.index(max(val_acc_per_epoch)) + 1
print('Best epoch: %d' % (best_epoch,))
```

The results from the tuner is used to build the model.

```
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test_enc, y_test)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
print(model.summary())
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(model, to_file='drive/MyDrive/Master/plots/results/before_game/nn_first.png')
```

The output from `model.summary()` and `plot_model` are empty.
The output looks like this:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
Total params: 137,329
Trainable params: 137,329
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
None
```

Don't know if this is connected, but the code runs perfectly fine, I just plot the network to see how it is built. I do however get an error when I am trying to save my model:

```
model.save('drive/MyDrive/Master/SavedModels/nn_first_before.csv')
```

and the error is:

```
KeyError: 'input_269_ib-0'
```

I don't know if these are related.

Comment: I know this is not what you're looking for, but for your own sake, look into `tensorboard`. Keras' visualization is... lacking in many ways.

Comment: What do you mean "*The code runs fine*"? Does the model get fitted? Do you get an accuracy and a best epoch printed? Plus, please *fix the indentation* in your `build_model` function.

Comment: Yes, the code gets executed, model get fitted.

Comment: But, because both summary and plot model is empty, I was wondering if there is an error in the code?

Comment: Please add all imports to your code in the question.

Comment: Done, Dr. Snoopy

Comment: There is no KeyError when I am only saving the weights, using model.save_weights()

Comment: It is quite inconvenient saving weights, do you know how to fix the error?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing imports from the `tf.keras` and `keras` libraries, which are not the same libraries and are incompatible, producing the strange problems you see here. Note your imports:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow import keras
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
```

Here you use some layers from the `keras` library, and other layers from the `tensorflow.keras` library, which will not work. Only use imports from one of these libraries.

Comment: Thank you!! This and the fact that I declared the model twice fixed it!!